# How to zip two arrays in Python and keep the original shape?

Tags: python, arrays

I have two different arrays that I would like combine with each other so that the new array has still the same shape as each of the old ones.

```
    import numpy as np

    x = (['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])
    y = (['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'])
    z = np.array(zip(x,y))        
    print z 
    print np.shape(z)
```

gets me

```
   [['1' 'a']
    ['2' 'b']
    ['3' 'c']
    ['4' 'd']
    ['5' 'e']
    ['6' 'f']
    ['7' 'g']
    ['8' 'h']
    ['9' 'i']]
    (9, 2)
```

and I would like to have

```
    [['1 a']
     ['2 b']
     ['3 c']
     ['4 d']
     ['5 e']
     ['6 f']
     ['7 g']
     ['8 h']
     ['9 i']]
     (9,)
```

since I need the new array to have only one dimension for further processing.
As I'm a newbie I think the zip() function could be not the right one, but I tried also the .join() function and I couldn't figure it out that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to join after zipping. Try this list comprehension:

```
z = [" ".join(item) for item in zip(x, y)]
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I meant!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class to hold both items for better access. For example,

```
import numpy as np

class Elem():
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


def create(lst):
    l = []
    for a, b in lst:
        l.append(Elem(a, b))
    return l

x = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
y = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
z = np.array(create(zip(x,y)))

print np.shape(list(z))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked too for me, however Michael Mulqueen's answer is easier for me to use as I'm only interested in the final array (z).

Answer (score 0):

```
x =(['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])
y = (['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'])
z =np.array(zip(x,y))
print z
print z[:,0].shape
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unfortunately this did not work for me as I got only the numbers when saving it in a new array.